# VLC audio and video stutter at very regular intervals while playing back a network stream

Tags: networking, sound, video, vlc

(Ubuntu 20.04)
I recently experienced a problem when trying to playback a network stream in VLC under Ubuntu 20.04. At regular intervals, the audio and and video would stutter briefly. The same network stream played back fine in MPV. The console was outputting the following two errors, repeatedly, every 2 seconds or so, lining up with the hitches:

```
ts error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS duplicate (received 0, expected 1) for PID 0
ts error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS duplicate (received 0, expected 1) for PID 4096
```

I wasn't able to find much mention of these errors anywhere, which is why I'm posting this question. I was able to learn that these errors are coming from the MPEG Transport Stream Demuxer. I was able to get the audio and video hitches to stop completely by going to:

preferences > input/codecs > demuxers > MPEG-TS

and changing the checkbox "check packets continuity counter" to off. It would appear that the demuxer was detecting false positive "duplicate" packets , and dropping these packets as a result, leading to the stutter. The console continues to be flooded with the same errors, even after changing this setting. I'm pretty sure that this is fine, though, and that the errors are as a result of some mistake on the part of whoever encoded the video.

Since I've solved my problem, I suppose this question doesn't need an answer, but I wanted to post it anyways-- I spent a good two hours trying to find the source of my issue, and nowhere found any mention of the "check packets" option causing problems. I only found that it solved my problem by fiddling with settings out of frustration and desperation. Hopefully I can save someone else the trouble!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the demuxer was causing the problem. It was getting confused and erroneously dropping packets. I'm not sure why, probably because the network stream was borked in some way. I tried changing a few of the parameters in

preferences > all > input/codecs > demuxers > MPEG-TS

and changing "check packets continuity counter" to off solved the playback issues completely. The error continues to print in the terminal but the player no longer drops the packets.

Comment: Hello, this is the answer section, not the question section, feel free to edit the original answer and add your comments rather than using the answer section, thank you.